# problemas de entrega en outlook.com

Tags: php, email, outlook

Tengo problemas al enviar correos electrónicos desde www.midominio.com a usurio@outlook.com, los mensajes se demoran de 2 a 3 horas en llegar a outlook y cuando llegan se van al correo no deseado.

Hable con mi proveedor de dominio, GoDaddy y me comenta que no estamos en lista negra, también al momento de hablar con el proveedor de hosting, me comento que todas las seguridades estan activadas y que al monitorizar el mail, le llega a outlook

Comment: Deberías poner mínimamente el código que estas utilizando para enviar los mails.

Comment: De hecho no es un problema de mail.dominio.com o lenguajes, el problema se dio que Outlook nos tenia en lista negra, para darse de baja accedimos al siguiente link [https://sender.office.com/]